# Event Delegation on jQuery resizable

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

My problem is larger than this example but I've composed an example test which exhibits the same behaviour.

The problem, how to attach/reattach the resizable event after dynamically adding an element to the page. I realise that this can be done with click events using something like `$('.table1').on('click', 'tr', function() {alert("clicked!");});` which will show the alert when a new tr is added to the table and it is clicked, this uses event delegation. However the examples for using jQuery Resizable do not appear to cater for this, so how can it be done?

Heres my test case (for simplicity this is in a single test file):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Event Delegation Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <style>
        #resizable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
        #resizable h3 { text-align: center; margin: 0; }
    </style>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
            $( function() {
                $( ".resizable" ).resizable();// <--- How to add a delegated event on this?
            } );

            $( "button" ).click( function () {
                $( "#size-region" ).append('<div id="2" style="width:150px; height: 100px;" class="ui-widget-content resizable"><h3 class="ui-widget-header">Not Resizable</h3></div>');
            } );
        } );
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="size-region" class="height: 90%; width: 100%;">
        <div id="1" style="width:150px; height: 100px;" class="ui-widget-content resizable">
            <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Resizable</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button>Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Docs for jQuery Resizable are at https://jqueryui.com/resizable/

Info on event delegation is found at https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

I mention the problem being larger, I believe i could just add the element with javascript for it but what if i have 10 other events to add? I'm specifically looking for a method where I can add a single js file and use this whatever is added to the size-region (if this is in fact possible)

Comment: I suspect a lot of the jQuery UI widgets are not going to be delegated well. Many rely on elements being in the DOM when initialized. The work around is to simply initialize them directly after the element is added dynamically. Let me see if resizable is one of these or not.

Comment: Hi Twisty would that mean adding the ```$( function() {
                $( ".resizable" ).resizable();
            } );``` snippet with any updated content? I have drag and drop too (also jQueryUI) so I guess a function might be nicer and call that?

Comment: It does not mean that and I hope I explained it better in my answer that has been posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  function makeResize(target) {
    return $(target).resizable();
  }

  makeResize(".resizable");

  $("button").click(function() {
    var c = ($(".resizable").length + 1)
    var newBox = $("<div>", {
      id: "resize-" + c,
      class: "ui-widget-content resizable"
    }).css({
      width: "150px",
      height: "100px"
    }).appendTo("#size-region");
    $("<h3>", {
      class: "ui-widget-header"
    }).html("Resize " + c).appendTo(newBox);
    makeResize(newBox);
  });
});
```

```css
#resizable {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

#resizable h3 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="size-region" class="height: 90%; width: 100%;">
  <div id="resize-1" style="width:150px; height: 100px;" class="ui-widget-content resizable">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Resize 1</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<button>Click me</button>
```

The initialization of a jQuery UI Widget cannot be delegated in the same way an Event can be. If you want to make a large number of elements be initialized with the same parameters, you can do this with a Function.

Looking at the `makeResize()` function, I pass in a variable, `target` that I then wrap so it is a jQuery Object and then initialize Resizable. This technique is very versatile as I can pass in a String, a element, or an object and it will work.

Examples:

```
$("button").click(function(){
  makeResize(this);
});
```

Makes the button that was clicked upon resizable.

```
$(document).on("click", "button", function(){
  makeResize(this);
});
```

Delegate the click event to any button that might be created and make it resizable.

I used more pure jQuery and this was my choice and it does not mean that your code, appending an HTML string, is wrong in any way. Two different approaches. I prefer my method as it is easier to read down the line, easier to manipulate or make small changes/fixes, and is easier to make more dynamic.

Your original code could work in a similar way:

```
$("button").click(function() {
  $("#size-region").append('<div id="2" style="width:150px; height: 100px;" class="ui-widget-content resizable"><h3 class="ui-widget-header">Not Resizable</h3></div>');
  makeResize("#2");
});
```

As the new HTML String has been added to the DOM, and is Rendered, we can call it by a selector, `"#2"`.

The pitfall here is that if you click the button a 2nd or 3rd time, you now have multiple elements with the same ID when they need to be unique.

Last note, you do not need to wrap the jQuery in more than one Ready or Anonymous function. You do want to let all the HTML Load and be Ready before you execute your jQuery. This is what `$(document).ready(function(){});` and `$(function(){});` do for you.

Comment: You sir are a star, thanks Twisty. I agree that creating the element in its constituent parts does look a lot cleaner than a convoluted html string. My initial non working code creates the snippets dynamically so any created would have a unique id but I omitted most of it for simplicity. You've given me a lot to work with here so I'm going to have a play with it and fingers crossed can fix my projects remaining show stopper issue.